# Absolute differences can be split into two sets with equal sums

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

Assume we have $n$ distinct real numbers. We replace these numbers with the absolute difference of each two of them. Prove that if $n$ is odd, then the resulting numbers can be divided into two sets of numbers, such that the sum of these two sets are equal.

We can order the numbers in descending order without changing the problem and by that get rid of the absolute function. How should I proceed? Does this have anything to do with number of pairs that can be chosen?

Comment: What have you tried?  A natural first step might be to try to prove it for $ n=3$ (the problem really doesn't make sense for $n=1$).  Perhaps try induction after that.

Comment: So with $n$ numbers we have $n(n-1)/2$ differences?

Comment: I've tried it for n=3 and n=5 but I couldn't generalise. It's like the generalisation step is just the same problem again. @lulu

Comment: yes. @marty cohen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As seen in the comments, you are stuck with the induction step. Consider the following decomposition just for the last two elements (when you induct) in the numbers $x_1<\cdots <x_{2n-1}<\color{blue}{x_{2n}<x_{2n+1}}.$
$$A=\{x_{2n+1}-x_{2n}\}\cup \{x_{2n+1}-x_i:1\leq i\leq n-1 \}\cup \{x_{2n}-x_j:n\leq j\leq 2n-1\}.$$
Take the rest of the elements in another set $B$ and conclude that both of them have as a sum $$nx_{2n+1}+(n-1)x_{2n}-\sum _{i=1}^{2n-1}x_i.$$

Comment: can I ask how you come up with these brilliant solutions? I am good at getting stuck at a question for hours to no avail:") so I appreciate some good advise@Phicar

Comment: @Dojou I guess practice. To be honest I tried to skip the induction process because I do not like it that much :P and I arrived to something quite complicated. Then, I decided to solve $n=3$ and $n=5$ and the way to go from $n=5$ to $n=3$ was the key. Try always little examples but without assuming much. That is the key I guess to everything. Sorry to not be much help with this. Keep practice and solving this nice questions :)

Comment: That was great:)) tysm! Do you have a particular book in mind for practice?@Phicar

Comment: @Dojou Here is the biggest platform to practice online :). Books depend on the subject. This I guess is discrete math, so I can suggest Discrete Math from Biggs.

Comment: Great help. Tysm again =D@Phicar